# How to allocate memory using C++ new instead of C malloc

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am now working on homework. There is one thing confused me and I need your advice.
The problem is quite simple and basic about memory allocation. I am currently studying the book C++ Primer after I learn C language. So I prefer to use `new` and `delete` to do the memory allocation which failed me for this problem. Here is the problem. The function `getNewFrameBuffer` is used to allocate allocate memory for `framebuffer : (sizeof)Pixel x width x height`, please note that `Pixel` is a user defined data type. And then return the pointer of the allocated memory. It works fine when I use `malloc()` function as below:

```
char* m_pFrameBuffer;
int width = 512, int height = 512;
//function call
getNewFrameBuffer(&m_pBuffer, width, height);

//function implementation using malloc
int getNewFrameBuffer(char **framebuffer, int width, int height)
{
     *framebuffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * width *height);
     if(framebuffer == NULL)
         return 0;
     return 1;
}
```

However, when I try using new keyword to allocate memory it will cause an unexpected termination of the program. Here is my code:

```
int getNewFrameBuffer(char **framebuffer, int width, int height)
{
     framebuffer = new char*[sizeof(Pixel) * width *height];
     if(framebuffer == NULL)
         return 0;
     return 1;
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot, everyone:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should allocate using `new char` not `new char*` as `new char*` will allocate that many pointers.
This has lead you to remove the `*` from `*frameBuffer =` meaning that the caller's `frameBuffer` parameter will not be changed.

Change the line to

```
*framebuffer = new char[sizeof(Pixel) * width *height];
```

Comment: Thanks The Dark, you pointed out the problem and offered a solution:) I will be careful and try my best to figure out what I want to allocate. Thx!

Comment: A more C++ way of doing this would be "new Pixel[width * height]"

Comment: An even more C++ way of doing this would be `std::vector<Pixel>(width * height)`.

Comment: Hi, Beanz and Chris, the framebuffer is pointer pointing to an array of chars. I think it is not right to write code like *framebuffer = new Pixel[width * height]. Am I right?

Comment: @Zengrui `*framebuffer = new Pixel[width * height];` allocates an array of `Pixel`s and returns a pointer to that array.  Which appears to suit your needs more than a `char[]` of the same size. After all, I assume you will be storing `Pixel`s in the frame buffer.  The vector solution does the same, but without the need to handle the memory allocation yourself. If you use it, do read up on `std::vector` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
*framebuffer = new char[sizeof(Pixel) * width *height];
```

Note the *;

Comment: Are you attempting to create an array of character pointers or a pointer to an array of characters.  Cause it looks like you should also do
    *framebuffer = new char[sizeof(Pixel) * width *height];

Comment: Oh I see, I want to create an array of characters. Thanks!! Drew:)